# Traveling to India from Europe via london

Tags: london, amsterdam, mumbai

I am an indian citizen working in Amsterdam (Dutch resident permit) and intend to travel to Mumbai. BA offers flight from Amsterdam to London City (LCY) and then a connection from London Heathrow to Mumbai. The same applies for my reverse journey. The questions is do i need to apply for a visa (Tranist/Visit)? I am simply connecting thru different airports in london and dont intend to go sight seeing! My residence permit is valid for my return journey and i dont have a valid schengen visa.

Pls advise.
Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI - as you have a resident permit, you don't need a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would [need a Visitor In Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes) as you are changing airports and will need to pass immigration/customs.

However, you are exempt:

> Transiting without a visa
>
> You might be eligible for ‘transit without visa’ if:
>
> - you arrive and depart by air
> - have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive
> - have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)
>
> One of the following must also apply:
>
> - you’re travelling to (or on part of a reasonable journey to) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for
>     that country
> - you’re travelling from (or on part of a reasonable journey from) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for
>     that country
> - you’re travelling from (or on part of a reasonable journey from) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and it’s less than 6 months
>     since you last entered that country with a valid entry visa
> - you have a residence permit issued by Australia or New Zealand
> - **you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland**

The bold exception applies to you.